# What's Google Sheets alternative to CountIFS that works with OR logic?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I have blood pressure data in two columns (SYS & DIA) and want to count the states according to these rules:

```
critical      SYS > 180   OR  DIA > 120 
high stage 2  SYS > 140   OR  DIA > 90  
high stage 1  SYS 130-139 OR  DIA 80-89 
elevated      SYS 120-129 AND DIA < 80  
normal        SYS < 120   AND DIA < 80
```

so that for

```
SYS DIA
120 73 (that's elevated)
123 81 (high stage 1)
112 83 (high stage 1)
129 68 (elevated) 
118 72 (normal)
119 80 (elevated)
```

The result should be

```
normal: 1
elevated: 2
high stage 1: 3
```

For "elevated":
=COUNTIFS(SYS;">=120";SYS;"<=129";DIA;"<80") seems to work fine.

How do I handle "high stage 1" and other cases with OR???

I'm also considering working around the issue by adding a third column (as shown above) with a description of state via something like:

=IFS(OR(ISBETWEEN(SYS;130;139);ISBETWEEN(DIA;80;89));"High stage 1";AND(ISBETWEEN(SYS;120;129);DIA<80);"Elevated") and so on...

and then I guess I can just count words in that column. Still, one formula for all these states will get kind of messy and I suppose I'm missing a cleaner solution.

Comment: It seems to me that you should only be worrying about non-normal definitions, with everything other than those conditions being considered "normal." As it is, my own typical blood pressure of 120/ 80 (or, say, 120 / 84) falls nowhere in your readings and would return an error (or, with IFERROR, a null). I recommend that you think through that and revise both your sheet and the post accordingly. Comment below if/when you've done this, and I'll take another look.

Comment: In addition, you seem to have your counts off within your post, even as you have it. I see 3 "elevated" and 2 "high stage 1," not 2 "elevated" and 3 "high stage 1."

Comment: There are rules missing for SYS being 140 or DIA being 90.

Comment: Also from your example (last row) SYS 119, DIA 80 should be **high stage 1** and not **elevated** according to your rules.

Answer (score 1):

see:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(IF(B11:B="",,
 IF(((A11:A>=120)*(A11:A<=129))*(B11:B<80), A4,
 IF((A11:A<120)*(B11:B<80), A5, 
 IF((A11:A>180)+(B11:B>120), A1, 
 IF((A11:A>140)+(B11:B>90), A2, 
 IF(((A11:A>=130)*(A11:A<=139))+((B11:B>=80)*(B11:B<=89)), A3)))))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can have a reference (1 on the screenshot) to lookup conditions by SYS or DIA values (presuming only whole numbers are used):

```
SYS   DIA   Condition
  0     0   normal
120    80   elevated
130    80   high stage 1
141    91   high stage 2
181   121   critical
```

Then using this reference a formula in one cell (2 on the screenshot):

```
=QUERY(
  FILTER(
    VLOOKUP(
      QUERY(
        SPLIT(
          FLATTEN(
            ROW(A9:A) & "♥" & {IFNA(MATCH(A9:A, H2:H6)), IFNA(MATCH(B9:B, I2:I6))}
          ),
          "♥"
        ),
        "SELECT MAX(Col2)
         GROUP BY Col1
         LABEL MAX(Col2) ''",
      ),
      {SEQUENCE(ROWS(J2:J6)), J2:J6},
      2
    ),
    A9:A <> "",
    B9:B <> ""
  ),
  "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL COUNT(Col1) ''",
)
```

[image]

If you need to get condition for every row (3 on the screenshot) you can use this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFS(
    A9:A = "",,
    B9:B = "",,
    True,
      VLOOKUP(
        QUERY(
          SPLIT(
            FLATTEN(
              ROW(A9:A) & "♥" & {IFNA(MATCH(A9:A, H2:H6)), IFNA(MATCH(B9:B, I2:I6))}
            ),
            "♥"
          ),
          "SELECT MAX(Col2)
           GROUP BY Col1
           LABEL MAX(Col2) ''",
        ),
        {SEQUENCE(ROWS(J2:J6)), J2:J6},
        2
      )
  )
)
```